# Why does my ImageView appear at the top?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-studio

I am very new to android and have been following a simple tutorial for a camera app. It shows a preview of the camera in an FrameLayout (towards the top) and then captures image after hitting a button directly below the FrameLayout. The image is then displayed in an ImageView that is supposed to be below the button. However, when I run the program and click the button to take a picture, the captured image appears on TOP of the FrameLayout. I have tried fixing this in the design tab of activity_main.xml but I can't seem to be able to locate the ImageView within the design, even though it is listed in my component tree.

Here are the three components from my xml file:

```
    <Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/camera_preview"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:text="@string/capture_button"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/text"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.143" />

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/camera_preview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="300dp"/>

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/captured_image"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
    android:contentDescription="@string/desc" />
```

Is there anything that I could do to fix this?

Comment: You want the ImageView appear below the Button ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want your imageView to appear below The Button and FrameLayout

Add this on your FrameLayout tag

`android:layout_below="@id/button"`

Your Edited Code.

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/camera_preview"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:text="@string/capture_button"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/text"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.143" />

<FrameLayout
android:id="@+id/camera_preview"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="300dp"
android:layout_below="@id/button"
    />

<ImageView
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/captured_image"
android:layout_below="@+id/camera_preview"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
android:contentDescription="@string/desc" />
```

Cheers!